# sp_getProcedureColumns

Tags: advantage-database-server

I have tried to pass in the proc name into procedureNamePattern and the procedure seems to return all the metadata for all the procedures. I pass in a empty string and I get the same results.

The following is the code used:

```
using (AdsCommand command = new AdsCommand { CommandText = "sp_getProcedureColumns", 
                                             Connection = connection, 
                                             CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure })
{
   AdsParameter param = new AdsParameter("@procedureNamePattern", DbType.String) { 
     Direction = ParameterDirection.Input, Value = originalProcedureName };
   command.Parameters.Add(param);

   AdsParameter param0 = new AdsParameter("@catalog", DbType.String) { 
       Direction = ParameterDirection.Input, Value = null };
   command.Parameters.Add(param0);

   AdsParameter param1 = new AdsParameter("@schemaPattern", DbType.String) { 
       Direction = ParameterDirection.Input, Value = null };
   command.Parameters.Add(param1);

   AdsParameter param2 = new AdsParameter("@columnNamePattern", DbType.String) { 
       Direction = ParameterDirection.Input, Value = null };
   command.Parameters.Add(param2);
```

Answer (score 0):

With stored procedures, you can use the `DeriveParameters` method.  That might make it simpler.  The following is an example:

```
AdsCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();    
cmd.CommandText = "sp_getProcedureColumns";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.DeriveParameters();
cmd.Parameters["ProcedureNamePattern"].Value = "MyProcName";
AdsDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

If you do not call the DeriveParameters method, then the underlying SQL statement that is generated is produced directly from the provided parameters in the given order.  That means you would need to provide the parameters in the order to match the procedure definition.  In this case, the ProcedureNamePattern parameter needs to be 3rd.  If you change the order of the `cmd.Parameter.Add()` calls, then your original example should work.

Comment: The sp_getProcedureColumns returns the metadata I need. When I pass in the proc name it returns all the metadata for all procedures. I just want the metadata for the procedure I pass in.

Comment: Why should I use DeriveParameters when sp_getProcedureColumns is supposed to return the metadata. I already know what the parameters being returned from the procedure. I just want it to return the parmeters for the procedure name I pass in.

Comment: @hsedidin, Sorry - I should have answered that more directly.  I'll update it.

Comment: I need to extract metadata from the procedures in order to generate WSDL's and Schemas.

Comment: I am developing a custom WCF Adapter for Advantage. This URL will provide more information http://www.microsoft.com/biztalk/technologies/wcflobadaptersdk.mspx